# Importing z-brush cube to 3ds max causes shadow issues

Tags: 3dsmax

I have created cube model in z-brush then I exported it to .obj format. Seems vertex count is the same as in 3ds max as in z-brush.

In all my viewports I see cube, but in perspective I see not a cube but some like "extra shadows" on the each side of cube, like cube has not plane sides.

When I render it it also has not plane sides and some ugly shadows. How can I fix it, maybe I should know some tricks about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your problem is due to normals not being per-face but smoothed.

You can apply Smooth with AutoSmooth after import with 30 degrees threshold to your model or maybe use a better exchange format.

You can use 30 degrees in most cases for half-smoothed objects.
If you need blockiness just decrease it.
(Or if you need smoothness increase it)

Comment: yes seems like normal issues, but I should do if I don't want to use smoothing? )

Comment: Smooth with autosmooth turned on and 0 threshold creates a completely blocky and rigid looking mesh(no smooth edges), so you can use it to remove smoothness as well.